# IsMemoryGrantFeedbackAdjusted missing in plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory-grant

Why would `IsMemoryGrantFeedbackAdjusted` and `LastRequestedMemory` properties be missing from our Actual Execition Plans?

We're using 2019 RTM CU18 (Standard Edition)

We realise memory grants are often ignroed for simple queries, but if i grab the plan for a more complex query we get all the normal grant info except the 2 new adaptive properties.

Is this because we're using standard edition?

If so, are adaptive memory grants still under the hood or is it disabled completley.

We've tried turning it on manually:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET ROW_MODE_MEMORY_GRANT_FEEDBACK = ON;
```

This made no difference, we then tried the example from Brent Ozar, that was also missing the new properties

[image]

Comment: Is it available in the query plan XML?

Comment: I guess, to SQL 2019's features are used, the cardinality estimation version model has to be 150, not 70. Check compatibility level of the database.

Comment: compat level is 150 (2019) - and the XML is also missing the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROW_MODE_MEMORY_GRANT_FEEDBACK` is not available in Standard edition.
I can image it therefor is not displayed. Perhaps the items are hidden in the XML. As Denis Rubashkin mentioned in the comments. Check also the Compability Level of the database.

Links:
[Supported features SQL 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver15)